# Enable Role Manager in my Asp.net MVC4 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, configuration, role-manager

How can i enable the Role Manager in my MVC4 application ? 
I need to add roles to my application users, and i need a summary on how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i needed, hope to help some one out their.

To enable the role manager, you need to add the corresponding tags to the web.Config file, and don't forget to change the enable= "tru"
in the role manager tag implecitily

You can find these tags of your ASP.Net applications on the : 
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config file

```
<membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```